# How to pass any object that can display text to a C# method

Tags: c#, user-interface, polymorphism

I'm trying to write a method of a class that should get an object (such as textbox or label) as a parameter and whenever it needs to show a message to the user it uses the object to show the message.

As the class will be used in other programs, it should be a little portable and it should implement the functioning to any text-based object such as labels or textboxs etc.

Consider the following method:

```
public void TcpEndPoint(string IP,/* a text-based object */)
{ 

    // There's a need to show a message 
    // to the user by the text-based object

}
```

Is there any way to implement this, or is this kind of programming is not proper for portable classes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would go for a different approach. Instead of passing in the text receiving object I would pass out the text using a delegate:

```
public void TcpEndPoint(string IP, Action<string> setText)
{
    setText(message);
}
```

This can then be called with a lambda expression:

```
TcpEndPoint(someIp, t => yourTextBox.Text = t);
```

Answer (score 1):

The thing you call `text-based object` is I assume [Windows.Forms.Control](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control(v=vs.110).aspx). This class is the base class for all visual objects in windows forms. So you can use that class and `get` it's `Text` property.

```
public void TcpEndPoint(string IP, Control _object)
{ 
    ...
    MessageBox.Show(_object.Text);/// or in any other way you like.
    ...
}
```

**updated:**

And if you want to `set` the `Text` property of the object and show the message **on** it, just use it like this:

```
public void TcpEndPoint(string IP, string message, Control _object)
{ 
    ...
    _object.Text = message; /// or in any other way you like.
    ...
}
```

Comment: I'm not going to use messageboxs. What I need is something like a label or textbox to show the message on the form. hope you got what I mean :)

Comment: No I don't get it :) try to eloborate your question then.